# Azure table service performance issues while querying data without partition and row keys

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have azure table schema which holds data about a car like VRN (Vehicle Registration Number) etc. There may also multiple entities (fewer) for a car. So I have not made VRN as partition key.

Now my most query search is "Get entities by VRN". This is impacting a major performance issue on querying data based on VRN as data entities grows on about more than a million in the table.

Comment: "There may also multiple entities (fewer) for a car. So I have not made VRN as partition key. " - Do you mean there are multiple entries for the same VRN? It seems to me that VRN can be used as 'partition key'. Car data will be partitioned using VRN. This will improve the query performance.

Comment: Yes. I have multiple entities for same VRN. Making VRN as partition key results in huge number of partitions as there will be millions of cars. Would this hit back with any performance or memory issues?. I mean indexing may take more memory or limit for partitions etc.

Comment: In that case, 'Range partitions' will be created if you make VRN as partition key. It will still be faster than current design. I am not entirely aware of your data model, hence can't advise on the best candidate for partition key. You can also consider combining couple of columns to form a key. Please refer to the link Zhaoxing Lu has shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying without PartitionKey and RowKey results in a whole table scan, which has terrible performance by design. Please refer to [Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide) about how to design your table per your query scenario.